# Filling ListView in homescreen widget in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-widget

I'm trying to create an android widget containing a list of elements (tasks).

When i place the widget on the homescreen it's empty, no one task is displayed.

I don't unnderstand what is missing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the xml for my widget_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/widget_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@+string/TASK_LIST_ACT" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

This is the layout for the items of the ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget_element"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
```

This is my widgetProvider class

```
package it.geotask.android.widget;

import it.geotask.android.R;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class TaskWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, GeotaskRemoteViewService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);

        rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.list, intent);

        rv.setEmptyView(R.id.list, R.id.empty_view);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
    }

}
}
```

And this is my RemoteViewsFactory

```
package it.geotask.android.widget;

import it.geotask.android.R;
import it.geotask.android.dto.Task;
import it.geotask.android.service.TaskService;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.RemoteViewsService;

public class GeoTaskRemoteViewsFactory implements
    RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

private Context context = null;
private int appWidgetId;

private List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();

public GeoTaskRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);


}

public int getCount() {
    return taskList.size();
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return taskList.get(position).getId();
}

public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.row);

    row.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, taskList.get(position)
            .getName());


    return (row);
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onCreate() {
    taskList = TaskService.getTaskInStateList(context, context
            .getResources().getString(R.string.DB_STATE_ACTIVE));
    taskList.addAll(TaskService.getTaskInStateList(context, context
            .getResources().getString(R.string.DB_STATE_IN_RANGE)));
    taskList.addAll(TaskService.getTaskInStateList(context, context
            .getResources().getString(R.string.DB_STATE_DELAYED)));

}

public void onDataSetChanged() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

The remoteViewsService simply returns an instance of the factory.

**EDIT:**
i forgot to declare the service in the manifest; now i get the widget filled with the correct number of items, but with the message "loading" instead of the name of the item i want to display

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved.
I was following the google example of stackWidget, and they use a for on the widgetIds array, incrementing the int cursor with ++i, it causes the widget not to work.
Used i++ and it works

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I'm seeing the number of items, but they all say "Loading..." and I have the for loop incrementing with i++.